# Exporting R data frame to a text file while defining the number of characters allowed in each column and spacing

Tags: r

I have the following data frame.

```
c1 <- c("Stop", "Go", "Stop", "Go", "Go")
c2 <- c(300,6,800000,20,7000)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)
```

I have been trying to use `write.table()` to export this data frame as a text file as follows.

```
write.table(df, file = "test", 
            quote = FALSE, 
            col.names = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE)
```

I want to define how many characters there are present in every element of each column so that I get the following output in the text file.

```
#Stop    300
#Go        6
#Stop 800000
#Go       20
#Go     7000
```

Where in column 1 every value has 4 characters and in column 2 every element has 6 characters and they are separated by one space. For example the value 6 in the data frame would be a character string with 5 spaces before the 6. In column 1 the characters are left justified with spaces after and in column 2 the spaces are before. How can I do this and what functions may be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format()` your data using the `width` argument.  This will left pad numeric and right pad character vectors by default.  Here the width is set to the maximum number of characters per column.

```
write.table(
  lapply(df, \(x) format(x, width = max(nchar(x)), scientific = FALSE)),
  file = "test.txt", 
  quote = FALSE,
  col.names = FALSE,
  row.names = FALSE)
```

Produces:

```
Stop    300
Go        6
Stop 800000
Go       20
Go     7000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach:

```
df$c2 <- format(df$c2, scientific = FALSE)
n <- sapply(df, function(x) 6-nchar(x))

df2 <- df
for(j in seq_len(ncol(n))){
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(n))){
    df2[i,j] <- paste0(df2[i,j], paste0(rep(" ", n[i,j]), collapse = ""))
  }
}

write.table(df2, file = "test.txt", 
            quote = FALSE, 
            col.names = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE)
```

output from txt file

```
Stop      300
Go          6
Stop   800000
Go         20
Go       7000
```